# $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{C}$ and holomorphic in $U=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\operatorname{Im} z\neq 0\}$, then $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

How can I show that if $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function such that $f$ is holomorphic (or analytic) in $U=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\operatorname{Im} z\neq0\}$, then $f$ is holomorphic in the whole $\mathbb{C}$.

Any hint would be really appreciated!

Comment: Use Morera's theorem. See [e.g. here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2083742/let-f-in-hol-bbbc-setminus-bbbr-cap-c-bbbc-then-int-gammafzd)

Comment: I thought about that @DanielFischer, but what should I do when the triangle have vertex in the the upper plane and also in the lower plane?

Comment: You split the triangle using the interval of $\mathbb{R}$ intersecting it. For each part, the integral over the closed cycle in the closed half-plane is $0$ by Goursat and continuity, and in the combination of the two cycles, the part on the real axis cancels, since it appears with opposite orientation.

Comment: thanks for the tips @DanielFischer, helped me a lot!!

Comment: @DanielFischer We discussed this 6 months ago. Applying Cauchy's integral theorem in each half-plane, I'm still thinking it is elementary to construct the holomorphic antiderivative ?

Comment: @reuns Constructing it is elementary. Showing that the constructed function is holomorphic and a primitive of $f$ isn't so much. If you define $F(z) = \int_0^z f(w)\,dw$ without specifying the path, you need to show that $F$ is well-defined, i.e. the value is independent from the choice of path, and that is work. If you specify the path as the straight line segment, you need to show that the integral over the boundaries of certain triangles vanishes. You only need to consider triangles with one vertex at $0$, and that is indeed marginally simpler than looking at all triangles, but the essence

Comment: of the argument is identical. If you specify some other path, you have the same problem, to show that $F' = f$ you need to show that the integral over certain closed paths vanishes so that you can replace $F(w) - F(z)$ by an integral over a short path.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oops your linked answer is actually the one we discussed. Constructing the holomorphic antiderivative in an elementary way is exactly what you do in it.