# Show that $f$ is analytic on $G$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Suppose $G$ is an open set and let $f:G \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ be a continuous function and assume $f$ is analytic on $G \setminus S$ where $S$ is a straight line joining $a$ and $b$ where $a,b \in G$. Then using Morera's theorem show that $f$ is analytic in $G$.

For any triangular region $T$ in $G$ not intersecting $S$ it is easy to see that $\int_{\partial T} f(z)\ dz = 0$ since $G \setminus S$ is also open. For the cases when one of the vertices of $T$ is lying on $S$ or $S$ is lying on a side of the triangle then how can I tackle those cases? Other cases will be dependent on these two cases. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Essentially, it's [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2083742/let-f-in-hol-bbbc-setminus-bbbr-cap-c-bbbc-then-int-gammafzd). There's a slight increase in inconvenience since here we need to restrict the shift parameter $h$ so that we're only looking at contours entirely within $G$ (which is automatically the case for $G = \mathbb{C}$), but that's minor.

Comment: Can you explain why does the set $\{z \in \mathbb C : \mathrm{dist} (z,\Delta) \leq 1 \}$ is a compact set?

Comment: It's closed (if $\operatorname{dist}(z,\Delta) = 1 + \varepsilon$, then $\operatorname{dist}(w,\Delta) \geqslant \operatorname{dist}(z,\Delta) - \lvert w-z\rvert > 1$ for $\lvert w-z\rvert < \varepsilon$, so the complement is open), and bounded ($\Delta$ is compact, hence bounded; if $\lvert w\rvert \leqslant M$ for $w\in \Delta$, then $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant M+1$ for $\operatorname{dist}(z,\Delta) \leqslant 1$). By Heine-Borel, it's compact.

Comment: $|z| \leq |z-w|+|w| \leq M + |z-w|$. Now $|z-w| \geq \mathrm{dist} (z,\Delta)$. Then how can the last inequality be obtained?

Comment: Since $\Delta$ is compact, there's a $w\in \Delta$ with $\lvert z-w\rvert = \operatorname{dist}(z,\Delta)$.